# Detecting a radiobutton change

Tags: vb.net, radio-button, detect

I have about 50 radiobuttons on one form and I don't want to create an if statement for each one to detect when one changes, they are not part of a group box. How would I detect if any radiobutton changed and then write the name to another variable?

Answer (score 5):

You could Always set the CheckedChanged event for all 50 radiobuttons to the same event handler.
This is an example done via code:

```
Private Sub OnChange(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim rb = CType(sender, RadioButton)
    Console.WriteLine(rb.Name + " " + rb.Checked.ToString)
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    AddHandler Me.RadioButton1.CheckedChanged, AddressOf OnChange
    AddHandler Me.RadioButton2.CheckedChanged, AddressOf OnChange
    ' and so on .....'
End Sub
```

I have done this via code and not using the designer to avoid the long add of `Handles RadioButton1.CheckedChanged, RadioButton2.CheckedChanged .......`

Answer (score 5):

Put all the radio buttons on a panel and loop through the panels radio button controls, programmatically adding the same event handler for each as described by @Steve. One way I like to handle the event is to assign each radio button an index into its tag property. Then just store any relevant data in a list of objects and access the data for that radio button by pulling out it's corresponding object from the list using its tag. Much easier than doing it by hand.

#### Edit: Good catch @Neolisk. Updated answer.

Comment: Loop through all *checkbox* controls. Yes, I was going to suggest this, then I noticed your answer. So have a +1.